# Invalid API call when using alpha vantage python wrapper with list argument

Tags: python, python-asyncio, alpha-vantage

I'm trying to pull multiple stock ticker data from the alpha vantage python wrapper in an iterative fashion as opposed to calling each individually.

It works if I pass a list of explicit values but when I introduce a postgresql populated list to parse through I get the Invalid API call. I'm at a loss.

The code works like this:

```
stock_symbols = ['X','Y','Z','A','B','C','etc] 

async def get_data(stock_symbol):
    
    # create alpha vantage timeseries object
    ts = TimeSeries(key = config.ALPHAV_KEY, output_format = 'pandas')
    data, _ = await ts.get_intraday(stock_symbol, interval = '5min', outputsize = 'full')
    await ts.close()
    return data

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [get_data(stock_symbol) for stock_symbol in stock_symbols]
group1 = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
results = loop.run_until_complete(group1)
loop.close()
print(results)
```

But passing the values like this throws the error:

```
 # connect to Database
connection = psycopg2.connect(host = config.DB_HOST, database = config.DB_NAME, user=config.DB_USER, password = config.DB_PASS)

cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id IN (SELECT product FROM old_products)")

rows = cursor.fetchall()

stock_symbols = []  
for row in rows:
    stock_symbols.append(row['symbol'])


async def get_data(stock_symbol):
    
    # create alpha vantage timeseries object
    ts = TimeSeries(key = config.ALPHAV_KEY, output_format = 'pandas')
    data, _ = await ts.get_intraday(stock_symbol, interval = '5min', outputsize = 'full')
    await ts.close()
    return data

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [get_data(stock_symbol) for stock_symbol in stock_symbols]
group1 = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
results = loop.run_until_complete(group1)
loop.close()
print(results)
```

So it's working as suggested at https://pypi.org/project/alpha-vantage/
but why won't it work passing the values in the same way ultimately as it's still passing a list through the function and into the get_intraday timeseries object call. Am I missing something obvious?

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test/Documents/Programming/VSCode/Ark_Funds_Tracking/pop_prices_EOD.py", line 34, in <module>
    results = loop.run_until_complete(group1)
  File "/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/envs/Py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/test/Documents/Programming/VSCode/Ark_Funds_Tracking/pop_prices_EOD.py", line 27, in get_data
    data, _ = await ts.get_intraday(stock_symbol, interval = '5min', outputsize = 'full')
  File "/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/envs/Py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alpha_vantage/async_support/alphavantage.py", line 164, in _format_wrapper
    call_response, data_key, meta_data_key = await func(
  File "/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/envs/Py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alpha_vantage/async_support/alphavantage.py", line 106, in _call_wrapper
    return await self._handle_api_call(url), data_key, meta_data_key
  File "/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/envs/Py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alpha_vantage/async_support/alphavantage.py", line 254, in _handle_api_call
    raise ValueError(json_response["Error Message"])
```

ValueError: Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY.

Comment: Have you done `print(stock_symbols)` to make sure it contains exactly what you expect, and not some accidental `None`s, maybe?

Comment: Yes, it prints a list of stock symbols. It's the interplay between the function and tasks (part of the documented way of approaching this api asynchronously) that I don't understand and think the problem may be arising there?

Comment: No, that's impossible.  Once you have `stock_symbols` as a list, no component knows nor cares where it came from.  The problem has to be that something in the database list is not a valid stock symbol.

Comment: The list prints 171 stock tickers, no strange characters or numbers, e.g. 'MBLY', 'SPR', 'CRNT', 'XMTR', 'TWST', 'WKME'...I've added the traceback to original post

Comment: If you don't print the stock symbols as you go, then you don't know which one it is complaining about.